# Question about writing a proof with continuous functions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

How would I write a proof for this example?

We know that all polynomial functions on the reals are continuous by using the sequential definition of continuity. In particular, we know that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous. Prove this using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.